# Error when using hyperref package in East Asian Journal on Applied Mathematics latex template

Tags: hyperref

I am writing a manuscript to be considered for publication in the East Asian Journal on Applied Mathematics. I'm using the journal's template obtained from https://www.global-sci.org/guide/guide.html?journal=eajam to typeset the manuscript in latex. The following is my working trial:

```
\documentclass{eajam}
%%%%% journal  info %%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand\thisnumber{x}
\renewcommand\thisyear {200x}
\renewcommand\thismonth{xxx}
\renewcommand\thisvolume{xx}
%%%%%%%%   end  %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{charter,lipsum}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}


%%%%% author macros %%%%%%%%%
% place your own macros HERE
%%%%% end %%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}



\markboth{F.~Author and A.~Co-Author(s)}{Short Title}
\title{Here is the Title}

% single author:
% \author[AUTHOR]{AUTHOR\corrauth}
% \address{address of AUTHOR}
% \email{{\tt email address of AUTHOR} (AUTHOR)}
%\author[Only Author]{Only Author\corrauth}
%\address{School of Mathematical Sciences, Beijing International University,
%Beijing 12345, China.}
%\email{{\tt email@address} (Only Author)}

% multiple authors:
% Please mark \corrauth after the name of the corresponding author.
% different addresses:
%\author[F.~Author and A.~Co-Author(s)]{First Author\affil{1}\comma\corrauth and Co-Author(s)\affil{2}}
%\address{\affilnum{1}\ address of First Author\\
%\affilnum{2}\ address of Co-Author(s)}
%
%same address:
\author[F. Author and A.~Co-Author,]{Amirul Aizad Ahmad Fuad and Tahir Ahmad\corrauth}
\address{Department of Mathematical Sciences, Faculty of Science,\\ Universiti Teknologi Malaysia, 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia}
%
\emails{{\tt fauthor@edu.eajam} (F. Author), {\tt Co-Auhor(s)@edu.eajam} (A. Co-Author)}
%
%%%%% Begin Abstract %%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should provide the application context and briefly summarise the main findings.
It should not be too long --- normally no longer than half a page.
\end{abstract}
%%%%% end %%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%% Keywords %%%%%%%%%%%
\keywords{At least 3 items and at most 5 items.}

%%%% AMS subject classifications %%%%
\ams{65M10, 78A48}

%%%% maketitle %%%%%
\maketitle

%%%% Start %%%%%%

\section{Preparation of Manuscript\label{sec2}}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

However, I get an error that reads "Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }," whenever I try to use `\usepackage{hyperref}. Please can someone show me how to solve this?

Comment: Hope the class file was customized not the standard, please provide the class file link from where to download else share the class file for further checking...

Comment: The class file is also provided in the link https://www.global-sci.org/guide/guide.html?journal=eajam. @MadyYuvi

Comment: I didn't face any issues, please ignore the error in first time compilation by entering the character `s` and then recompile twice ...hope it may solve the issue...

Comment: Where do I enter the character s? Please can you clarify on this @MadyYuvi?

Comment: What `OS` (Windows or Mac) you are using and What type of `TeX` engine (`LaTeX, PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX`, etc.) you are using for compilation?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and Latex for compilation @MadyYuvi

Comment: @AmirulAizad - Which front-end editor to you employ? And which TeX distribution -- MikTeX, TeXLive, something else? -- do you use?

Comment: If you using `Windows 10` then I assume you are using `MS-DOS` prompt to run your `LaTeX` file? is it correct???

Comment: I'm using MikTeX @Mico

Comment: @AmirulAizad - Please also answer my other question: Which front-end editor to you employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAJAM does not work with hyperref package.

Comment: @Amirul Aizad If you need help preparing your article for EAJAM, please contact eajam@global-sci.org

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This posting currently reads more like a comment than an answer. To convert your posting into a standalone answer that's useful as a reference for future readers, it would be very helpful if you clarified what "does not work" means. After all, the user @MadyYuvi has commented that it's possible to complete the compilation process if one is willing to hit "S" (short for "Scroll) when LaTeX reaches the first choke point. Do you disagree with MadyYuvi? If so, in which sense? Is there maybe a downside to his/her suggested way of proceeding?